# Debugging a TCP client/server pair of applications on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, python, .net-framework, debug

I have a server application in .NET 6/VS2022 which creates a TCP listener, and a python 3 application which creates a socket to connect to the server application.

Rather than hopping back and forth between VS2022 and PyCharm with breakpoints in each, is there any way I can view the network communication, including contents with bytes and ASCII decode, source and remote endpoint, and source and remote process names and ids?

Wireshark doesn't have an option to filter by pid (afaik), and both the first party Microsoft tools appear to be deprecated ([Microsoft Network Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Network_Monitor) and Microsoft Message Analyzer).

Comment: It sounds like you have the source code for both the server and the client.  Why don't you create your own debug log?

Comment: Why do you need to filter by process? The connection would be uniquely identified by its endpoints' addresses and ports. You control which ports are used.

Comment: @DanielB Maybe I'm being pedantic, but I don't *need* to do any of this. To answer your question though, I can't know ahead of time what the client side port will be. However after some testing I think I've found the solution with the filter `tcp.port == 8932`, I didn't expect this to work but it appears the devs of wireshark made this match either local or remote port #.